# Invalid data for boolean

Tags: pointers, ada

I have an error in my code. This error don't always appears and I don't know how to debug it.

Error is :

> Exception name: CONSTRAINT_ERROR
>
> Message: myFile.adb:42 invalid data
>
> value 84 not in 0..1

The referenced line is this one :

```
procedure myProcedure (ObjectA : in     Ptr_Type;
                       ObjectB : in out T_Type) is
Begin 
    ObjectB.BOOL := ObjectA.BOOL; (line 42)
end procedure;
```

With

```
-- How myProcedure is called :
varA : aliased T_Type;
varB : aliased T_Type;
-- varA and varB are used many times
myProcedure(ObjectA => varA'Unrestricted_Access,
            ObjectB => varB);


-- Where :
type T_Type is record
    ...
    BOOL : Boolean;
end record;    
type Ptr_Type is access all T_Type;
```

It seems to be that the code is trying to put 84 in a Boolean but I don't know how to debug that.

How can I do ?

EDIT : add more details

Comment: sounds like an uninitialized variable. On Linux, you could try running with valgrind/memcheck

Comment: If you’re going to ask why some code doesn’t work, you at least need to show us code that _compiles_! See [mcve]. As it stands, your code just won’t compile, because in the body if `myProcedure` you write to an `in` parameter. It’s much easier to show code that compiles if you try to show the code in the correct order, rather than working backward through the declarations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your assignment statement in the procedure:

```
procedure myProcedure (ObjectA : in     T_Type;
                       ObjectB : in out Ptr_Type) is
begin 
   ObjectA.BOOL := ObjectB.BOOL; (line 42)
end procedure;
```

You see, this ObjectA is "in" parameter - and hence you can't assign to it.

EDIT:
Now that the question been fixed the problem is obvious.

Neither of the variables are initialized - and in such case, if possible, invalid value will be chosen as default initialization.

Comment: Sorry it's a typo, the in/out are correct (I'll edit my question)

Answer (score 1):

First, if you can, alter the `BOOL : Boolean;` to `BOOL : Boolean := raise Program_Error with "Uninitialized Value";`
Try using `ObjectA.BOOL := ObjectB.all.BOOL;`, too.

Comment: I'll try your solution but I'm unable to reproduce the error. Can you explain to me what is `Object.all` ?

Comment: Object.all is dereference.